# I broke my Angular Fire Database list when I implemented an index signature on my constructor

Tags: angular

I am working on a project, and when I used inline annotation to the `itemsMap` in the constructor of the `shopping-cart.ts`, I no longer can see my list on my shopping cart.

I believe the issue has to do with the mapping that took place in the shopping-cart service.

*When it comes over to the shopping-cart it is coming as `undefined`.*

**shopping-Cart.service.ts**

```
async getCart (): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
  let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId ();
  return this.db.object<ShoppingCart>('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges()
  .map(cart => new ShoppingCart(cart.itemsMap));
}
```

**Shopping-Cart**

```
import { ShoppingCartItem } from './shopping-cart-item';


export class ShoppingCart {
  items: ShoppingCartItem[] = [];


  constructor(public itemsMap: { [productId: string]: ShoppingCartItem }) {
    for (let productId in itemsMap) {
      let item = itemsMap[productId];
      this.items.push(new ShoppingCartItem(item.product, item.quantity));
    }
  }

  get totalItemsCount() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let productId in this.itemsMap) {
      if (this.itemsMap.hasOwnProperty(productId)) {
        count += this.itemsMap[productId].quantity;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

**Shopping Cart item**

```
import {Product} from './product';

export class ShoppingCartItem {
  constructor (public product: Product, public quantity: number) {}
  get totalPrice() { return this.product.price * this.quantity}
}
```

**Product.ts**

```
export interface Product {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}
```

**Shopping-Cart.html**

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
<ng-container *ngIf='cart$ | async as cart'>
  <p>
    you have {{cart.totalItemsCount}} items in your shopping cart.
  </p>
<table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of cart.items">
      <td>
        {{item.product.title}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{item.quantity}}

      </td>
      <td>
        {{item.totalPrice}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

**I would like to display the list for my shopping cart.**

Comment: what if you console.log your cart in your map ?

Comment: That is what I have been trying to figure out how to do also. I do not know how to make the console.log work in this case to debug.

Comment: I used the .do operator to console.log and the list exists before the map, but after the map the cart.itemsMap comes back undefined.

Comment: `.map(cart => {console.log(cart); return new ShoppingCart(cart.itemsMap));}`

Comment: Here are the results. Before the map function all the items exist however after the line that maps the items the console returns this> ShoppingCart {itemsMap: undefined, items: Array(0)}

Comment: `async getCart (): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
  let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId ();
  return this.db
  .object<ShoppingCart>('/shopping-carts/' + cartId)
  .valueChanges()
  .do( x => console.log(x))
  .map(x => {console.log(x); return new ShoppingCart(x.itemsMap);})
  .do(x => console.log(x))

}`